# Working with quotient map and connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $p: X \rightarrow Y$ be a quotient map and assume that X is connected. The question is whether its fibre is connected too.

I am not sure if I understand fibre over x correctly, but am I asked to show that whether $f^{-1}({x})$ is connected?

There is a similar question related to the same topic. The questions starts out with a quotient map p and assume Y is connected, the subspace $p^{-1}({y}) \subseteq X$ {fibre over y) is connected and the question asks to show X is connected.

If my notation for the fibre of x is correct, what does $f^{-1}({x})$ actually mean? Let's say $f(x) \in Y$ for some $x \in X$. Then $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x = f^{-1}(y)$ and thus $f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(f^{-1}(y))$. Am I right?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that $x\in X$?

Comment: Hmm, yes. Why did you cast doubt on that condition?

Comment: Becasue I have never seen a notation like $f^{-1}(x)$ for $f :X\to Y$ and $x\in X$.

Comment: I don't know. I am trying to work through this question. My interpretation may not even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

For f:X -> Y, A subseteq Y, $f^{-1}(A)$ = { x : f(x) in A }.
$f^{-1}(y)$ = { x : f(x) = y }.

f:R -> S^1 (the unit circle), x -> (sin x, cos x),
the quotient map wrapping R around the circle, has disconnected fibers.

The simular question is false.  What is true is that if **all** the fibers
of a connected space are connected, then the domain space is connected.
Likewise for compact.